# Prisma Findmany Many to Many get all information

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma

In **Prisma FindMany Include** example (https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/quickstart), we have the data model as:

```
model User {
  id    Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  email String  @unique
  name  String?
  posts Post[]
}

model Post {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  title     String
  content   String?
  published Boolean @default(false)
  author    User    @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId  Int
}
```

and the findMany function as:

```
...

async function main() {
  const usersWithPosts = await prisma.user.findMany({
    include: {
      posts: true,
    },
  })
  console.dir(usersWithPosts, { depth: null })
}

...
```

the result is:

```
[
  { id: 1, email: 'alice@prisma.io', name: 'Alice', posts: [] },
  {
    id: 2,
    email: 'bob@prisma.io',
    name: 'Bob',
    posts: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Hello World',
        content: null,
        published: false,
        authorId: 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So, on **posts** JSON result we have id, title, content, published and **authorId.**

My question is: can i have the **author name?** is there a way to get it? I want the result like this:

```
[
  { id: 1, email: 'alice@prisma.io', name: 'Alice', posts: [] },
  {
    id: 2,
    email: 'bob@prisma.io',
    name: 'Bob',
    posts: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Hello World',
        content: null,
        published: false,
        authorId: 2,
        name: 'Bob', // I want the name here to show in the front-end directly
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is there any way to do this? thanks.

I tried doing a include inside the include and other things but all gives an server error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solve the question (reporting just for someone who is stucked in this question like me):

```
const result = await prisma.openings.findMany({
         include: {
            creator: {
               include: {
                  user: true,
               }
            },
            labels: {
               include: {
                  openingLabel: true,
               }
            }
         },
      });
```

You can nest includes like this...